# How does one show that a vector in $W$ and $W^{\perp}$ must be the zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I think the intuition is obvious I just can't form a satisfying concise and rigorous argument for it. Intuitively for $v$ to be in both $W$ and its orthogonal complement then it must be perpendicular to both spaces, but if its not zero and say its in $W$, then its not perpendicular to $W$, so that can't be. Likewise it can't be in $W^{\perp}$ for the same reason. But zero does satisfy both.

So rigorously I tried to write it as follow. We know $v \in W$ and $v \in W^{\perp}$. Thus, $v \perp W$ and $v \perp W^{\perp}$. Consider what these pair of statements mean:

1. $v \in W$ and $v \perp W$
2. $v \in W^{\perp}$ and $v \perp W^{\perp}$

so the first one says that $v$ is both in $W$ and perpendicular to it. If it were in $W$ (and not zero) then it must be parallel to some vector in $W$ so it can't be perpendicular to $W$. Thus, it must be zero. The same thing for $W^{\perp}$. This means that $v = 0$ and only $v=0$.

I feel there is something missing in my proof. Can someone point out what it is? I feel the **only** 0 is the missing part. Or is it ok?

Comment: "it must be parallel to some vector in W so it can't be perpendicular to W" <- You probably mean it must be a linear combination of  some vectors in W?

Comment: If $v$ is both in $W$ and $W^\perp$, then it must be orthogonal to *itself*.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist what I mean was that since $v \in W$ then $v$ must be parallel to some vector in $W$. Obviously, right? It should be parallel at least to the one you referenced, to the one that satisfies $v = \sum_i \alpha_i w_i$.

Comment: @amd I would take it one step further, it must be parallel and orthogonal to *itself*. Thats what I guess I was trying to prove in the end...that a vector with such properties is only the zero vector.

Comment: Parallelism to anything is extraneous. Orthogonality to every element of $W^\perp$ and positive definiteness of the inner product is all you need.

Comment: @amd maybe its psychological but to me seeing a vector parallel and at the same time perpendicular seems nearly like a contradiction. So it seems the only way to reconcile this contradiction is to collapse it to zero. Thats why I found it a helpful image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$<v,v>=0$ since $v\in W$ and the orthogonal of $W$. This implies that $v=0$ since its norm is zero.

Comment: sorry if this is a dum question but why does it matter if its norm is zero?

Comment: because if the norm of a vector is zero, this vector is the zero vector, see the definition of a norm.

Comment: @CharlieParker Inner products are positive-definite: $\langle v,v\rangle=0$ iff $v=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$v\cdot v=0\implies \vert v\vert^2\cos0=0\implies \vert v \vert^2=0 \implies \vert v \vert =0 \implies v=0 $